# Seekbar Doesnt move while playing

Tags: android

I have recorded audio, and play it through the mediaplayer. Recording, playing works fine. I used a seekbar, while playing the recorded voice. I used the following coding to play the content stored in sdcard. It works fine.. mFileName is the audio file in sdcard.
The seek bar doesnt move, while playing. Any suggestions...

```
      private void startPlaying()
{

 MediaPlayer mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

    try {
        mPlayer.setDataSource(mFileName);
        mPlayer.prepare();
         mPlayer.start();
        mSeekBar.setMax(mPlayer.getDuration());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
    }
}
```

And I used

```
    mSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(fromUser){
                mPlayer.seekTo(progress);
                mSeekBar.setProgress(progress);
            }
        }
    });
    Thread currentThread  = new Thread((Runnable) this);
    currentThread.start();

 public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        while(mPlayer != null){
            int currentPosition = mPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            Message msg = new Message();
            msg.what = currentPosition;
            threadHandler.sendMessage(msg);
        }
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private Handler threadHandler = new Handler(){
    public void handleMessage(Message msg){

        mSeekBar.setProgress(msg.what);
    }
};
```

The progressbar moves only when the user moves. It doent move atomatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The seekbar isn't going to magically update itself to show the MediaPlayer's current position.  Here's a link that shows how to do this with a polling thread that checks the MediaPlayer's position every second or so and updates the seekbar accordingly:

http://united-coders.com/nico-heid/an-android-seekbar-for-your-mediaplayer

Comment: I implement that too. But it doesnt work. See the code get edited.

Comment: Your `run()` method is not implemented like the sample. `Thread.sleep` should be inside the `while` loop, not after it. Try getting the linked sample to work correctly first, and then start to modify the sample code in the direction you want to go.